# PyCharm incorrectly assumes object is instance of BaseClass after calling issubclass()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, subclassing

I am running this test with Python 3.10.9 and PyCharm 2022.2.1 (Community Edition). This is an issue with PyCharm, not Python itself.

In my example code, I use a generator method that takes in a class type as an argument, and constructs the class. I want to make sure the class type that is passed is a subclass of `BaseClass`, so I use `issubclass()` on the `class_type` argument:

```py
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(foo='hi')
        self.bar = "hello"


def generate_sub_class(class_type):
    assert issubclass(class_type, BaseClass)
    new_obj = class_type()      # <--- PyCharm warning: "Parameter 'foo' unfilled"
    return new_obj


# Main
new_subclass = generate_sub_class(SubClass)
print(f"Type of new_subclass: {type(new_subclass)}")
print(f"new_subclass.foo: {new_subclass.foo}")
print(f"new_subclass.bar: {new_subclass.bar}")     # <--- PyCharm warning: "Unresolved attribute reference
                                                   #                        'bar' for class 'BaseClass'"
```

This code works as expected when running in Python, as we get the following output:

```bash
Type of new_subclass: <class '__main__.SubClass'>
new_subclass.foo: hi
new_subclass.bar: hello
```

However, as you can see with the code above, as soon as I call `issubclass(class_type, BaseClass)`, PyCharm now thinks that the constructed object is a `BaseClass` object. The constructor call has a warning because it is looking at the wrong constructor, and the `new_subclass.bar` call in Main has a warning because it doesn't see `bar` in `BaseClass`, even though it is a `SubClass` object as verified by the Python output.

Does anybody know why this would be happening? It seems like a PyCharm error to me, I have no idea why simply calling `issubclass` would make PyCharm assume the object is the BaseClass. Without the call to `issubclass`, PyCharm has no issues understanding that it is an instance of `SubClass`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Did you open an issue? This might be a PyCharm bug. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it's not really a bug, but a side effect of not providing any type hints. PyCharm starts with the assumption that `class_type` as the type `Any`, meaning any value could be assigned to the name and that value can be used with any operation, regardless of type.

So what does PyCharm do with the `assert` statement? It tries to apply type narrowing, assigning `class_type` a more specific type than `Any` when the assertion is true. The most general type that makes the assertion `True` is `BaseClass`, so in the code that follows the assertion, it assumes that `class_type` has the type `BaseClass`, not `Any`. (If the assertion failed, it doesn't need to assume anything, because none of the following code would execute.)

Once the type has been narrowed to `BaseClass`, the rest of the warnings are self-explanatory. `BaseClass` *isn't* provide the argument `BaseClass.__init__` expects, and direct instances of `BaseClass` *don't* have `bar` attributes.

At runtime, everything is fine because there are no assumptions about the type of `class_type`; it *is* `SubClass`, and so the code executes as expected.

---

That said, I don't have PyCharm installed to test. `mypy` does nothing, which leads me to suspect that PyCharm is being overly aggressive in performing type narrowing compared to `mypy`. What happens if you provide explicit type hints, for example,

```
from typing import TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseClass)

def generate_sub_class(class_type: type[T]) -> T:
    assert issubclass(class_type, BaseClass)
    new_obj = class_type()
    return new_obj
```

Here, the type hint provides the same amount of information that could be inferred from the `assert` statement, but since the type hint already implies that `T` could be bound to `BaseClass` or a subclass of `BaseClass`, no type narrowing should be necessary or applied.

Comment: I guess in mypy since the function signature isn't annotated, the body is just ignored.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the issue in `mypy` with an explicit hint of `Any`, though. (Unless `mypy` strips explicit `Any`s before deciding if a function is annotated?)

Comment: You are correct about the `class_type` being `Any`, so yeah this must be due to type hinting. I have never used type hinting in actual python code, so maybe this will be a good reason to try it out.

Comment: @chepner I tested your code both with `type[T]` and with `typing.Type[T]`, and the warning still persists as long as the assert statement is there. However, it did fix the warning in Main thanks to the return hint. So I think the answer is just that I need to use type hinting in the signature instead of assertions

Comment: Yeah, I can confirm using `reveal_type` that `class_type` remains `typing.Any`. Again, not sure why, since it probably should be narrowed, according to: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to @chepner, the best way to suppress the PyCharm warnings and make PyCharm understand the type correctly, is to use type hinting INSTEAD of asserting.
Specifically:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type
T = TypeVar('T', bound=BaseClass)

def generate_sub_class(class_type: Type[T]) -> T:
    new_obj = class_type()
    return new_obj
```

All warnings are now gone.

Comment: This still has the same underlying problem: Passing `BaseClass` (rather than `SubClass`) to `generate_sub_class` will fail, but it obeys the type hints you've given. Neither your `assert issubclass(...)` nor `Typevar(..., bound=...)` requires a proper subclass, the parent class is allowed too. And subclasses are not required to all have the same constructor signatures, so this is perilous in a lot of additional ways.

Comment: Yeah, IOW, PyCharm was **correctly understanding the type**. And correctly pointing out that as annotated, this isn't type-safe. With this code, `mypy` correctly complains: `test.py:18: error: Missing positional argument "foo" in call to "BaseClass"  [call-arg]`

Comment: @Blckknght So is there a way to provide a type-hint that correctly defines the parameter as a subclass of BaseClass, but not a BaseClass itself? I am new to type hinting, I've always just made docstrings...